# How can I retrieve query results as array in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, mysqli

Im working on a small PHP project and im changing from MySQLi to PDO , im also using prepared statements now.

I have managed to connect to the database and execute a query but I want to know how I can retrieve the results as an array?

I use the fetch_assoc() function in MySQLi to do this but now im using PDO and Prepared statements  , i dont know how to accomplish this.

My code so far...

```
    $res = $connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM ad WHERE id = :id");
    $res -> bindValue(':id',$id);
    $res -> execute();
```

I have heard of using this code but it doesnt work?

```
    $z= $res -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $productname =  $z['productname'];
```

Comment: fetchALL returns array of the resultant data with index 0 - n. And you can use the key like 'productname' in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$z` is now a multi-dimensional array, and as such, if you want to access the first row, you could just explicitly access index zero:

```
echo $z[0]['productname'];
```

It should look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array // index zero
        (
            [id] => 1
            [productname] => productname 1 // sub index
        )
        // $z[0]['productname']
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [productname] => productname 2
        )
        // $z[1]['productname']
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [productname] => productname 3
        )
        // $z[2]['productname']
)
```

If you want to access all the row sets, just use the good ol' `foreach`:

```
foreach($z as $row) {
    echo $row['productname'];
}
```